# chakra ui custom theme doesnt give autocomplete for custom varients

Tags: typescript, autocomplete, themes, chakra-ui

I have an extended Chakra UI theme (**`extendedConfig`**) in my React project, which includes custom variants for text styles. While the custom variants work fine, I'm not getting autocomplete when I try to use them in my components like **`<Text variant={''}>`**. I'm using TypeScript, and I've also tried adding **`satisfies ThemeOverride`** and using the Chakra UI CLI, but to no avail.

Here's how I'm trying to use the ChakraProvider:

```
<ChakraProvider theme={myTheme satisfies ThemeOverride}>
  {children}
</ChakraProvider>
```

Can anyone help me understand why I'm not getting autocomplete for my custom text variants, and how I can fix it?

Comment: The CLI is the answer and is necessary to make this work. Try that again, and once you have successfully ran it tell us what the type of `variant` is on `Text` when you hover it. BTW after running the CLI, restart your editor. Sometimes it does not pick up on the new typings since chakra cli writes them to node_modules.